# Custom Validation Message in Laravel Spark

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

Need to change the validation message in Laravel Spark, I am adding new fields in the registration form but needs to change the message shown.

Normal Laravel I can pass rules and custom messages to validation function but not sure how I can do in Spark.

```
Spark::validateUsersWith(function () {
  return [
   'name' => 'required|max:255',
   'company' => 'required_if:ptype,Company',
   'contact' => 'required',
   'country' => 'required_if:ptype,Company',
   'residence' => 'required_if:ptype,Creator',
   'nationality' => 'required_if:ptype,Creator',
   'ptype' => 'required',
   'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
   'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
   'vat_id' => 'max:50',
   'terms' => 'required|accepted',
   ];
});
```

Default error message: The company field is required when ptype is Company.

What I need is: Company field is required.

Comment: Try just overriding them in your **resources/lang/en/validation.php** file in the `custom` section.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize error messages used by the form request by overriding the `messages()` method. Example:

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'title.required' => 'A title is required',
        'body.required'  => 'A message is required',
    ];
}
```

And then you can pass them as a third parameter like this:

```
$this->validate($request, rules(), messages());
```

Rererence: [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#form-request-validation)

Comment: Thats in normal Laravel what about in Spark. There is a different way of doing it.

Comment: Did you try to do it this way, do you get any errors?